# Buildozer Unknown command/target android_old

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

im very noob still in python and kivy.

Anyways, I'm making a simple android app, which just showing a single label. 
Now I'm trying to package that python file to an apk via buildozer.
The `buildozer init` works, but then the `buildozer -v android debug` doesnt and give an error `Unknown command/target android_old`.

Anyone can help me resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late to answer this question but I had the same problem since I am new to this field too.
It seems that buildozer is not compatible with windows, instead you can use Google Colab.

Google Colab provides CPU to run your python code and it is Ubuntu based.

Refer the following link to run your code on Google Colab
https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af

Answer (score 0):

You must have a Linux or OSX computer to be able to compile for Android on Windows. So, on Windows to do so you need first to enable Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and install a Linux distribution: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install.