# .buildozer and bin folders are not created

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build an android app using buildozer. On my windows 10 device, I am running python 3.9.6, and I've installed buildozer version 1.2.0 and kivy version 2.0.0.

Problem is that when I press `buildozer init` in my folder `NewApp`, there is no bin folder or .buildozer folder created there. It just creates a buildozer.spec file. Now that I wish to access buildozer templates, I am having trouble finding them since there is no folder named .buildozer in the root folder `NewApp`.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#init-and-build-for-android), that's what `buildozer init` is supposed to do.

Comment: Oh @JohnAnderson, seems like it has changed since [this](https://www.amazon.com/Building-Android-Python-Using-Studio/dp/1484250303) book is written. Can you please tell how do I access the templates then?

Comment: I suggest following the instructions in the above mentioned documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildozer is always that way. That book might have missed saying that you need to build it once before you can access `.buildozer` folder and its contents.

If you want to access buildozer template or want to play around p4a contents, you **need to build it once**, doesn't matter if it fails.

You can build using below commands depending upon what you're targeting inside your project folder where you have `buildozer.spec` file.

- If creating for Android,

```sh
buildozer -v android debug
```

- If targeting iOS,

```sh
buildozer -v ios debug
```

Comment: Where do I have to use this command (in cmd as well as in python environment, both are showing error)? Also, would that command work in windows?

Comment: You need to run this command in terminal inside your project directory where you've your `buildozer.spec` file. You'd need WSL on windows for buildozer to work.

Comment: Even that doesn't work, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTjhw.png).

Comment: I see. Must be something to do with Windows. I personally don't have any experience using bulldozer on windows but I've seen people in Kivy community claiming to use bulldozer usin WSL.

Comment: Similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176947/buildozer-unknown-command-target-android-old
You may want to ask this in the community on discord

Comment: Ok, seems like what I want to do isn't possible on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a virtual machine on your PC. The VM (Virtual Machine) should be running on Linux (Ubuntu). WSL(2) still have a lot of problems. You can then install Buildozer on Ubuntu easily. Once installed, you can execute build by running the the following command on the terminal : buildozer -v android debug